# ¿Cómo puedo buscar palabras a través de sus caracteres?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente problema que necesito resolver en lenguaje C. El problema es el siguiente, debo conseguir que mi programa haga lo siguiente: Buscar palabras a través de sus caracteres o letras iniciales. para esto tengo un puntero que tiene guardado tres nombres: 'juan', 'jhon', 'miguel'.

Lo que debo conseguir es que si el usuario ingresa por el teclado la letra j, el programa me debe mostrar los nombres que contienen estas letras. En este caso seria 'jhon' y 'juan' descartando el nombre 'miguel'. Y si el usuario ingresa más de un carácter alfabético, mostrar los nombres que tengan esos caracteres.

Un ejemplo seria si el usuario ingresa por el teclado las letras 'jh', el programa debe mostrar solo el nombre de 'jhon' descartando 'juan' y 'miguel'.

Aquí tengo una parte del código que hice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){

printf("escriba su caracter: \n");
char *nombres_rok[] = {"juan","jhon","miguel"};   
char *caracter = "j";
char *resultado;

for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++){

//  resultado = strchr(*nombres_rok,*caracter);
 if(caracter == nombres_rok[i]){
printf("%s\n",nombres_rok[i]);
}
//       printf("los nombres del puntero son: %s\n",resultado);

}


}
```

Comment: Una pregunta, importa el orden de los caracteres o solo tienen que estar en la palabra? Digamos si pongo `jn` me deverian salir `jhon` y `juan` o no deveria salirme nada?

Comment: si agregas jn como hay dos palabras que tienen esos dos caracteres te debería mostrar las dos palabras el orden de los caracteres no importa lo importante es que te muestre solo las palabras que coincidan o que tengan los mismos caracteres

Comment: Tomas tu lista de palabras y tu lista de caracteres. Para cada uno de los caracteres: Pasas por cada palabra, si la palabra no tiene el caracter la eliminas. Asi terminas solo con las coincidencias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > ¿Cómo puedo buscar palabras a través de sus caracteres?

Puedes usar la función [strpbrk](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strpbrk/). La firma de esta rutina es:

```c
char * strpbrk ( const char * str1, const char * str2);
```

La función retornará `NULL` si no hay coincidencias de los caracteres de `str2` en `str1`.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *nombres_rok[] = {"juan","jhon","miguel"};   
    char str[30];
    printf("Escriba una cadena: ");
    scanf("%29s", str);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        if(strpbrk(nombres_rok[i], str) != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", nombres_rok[i]);
        
    return 0;
}
```